# How to fix '401 Unauthorized' Passport-jwt + Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, passport-jwt

Im working on a WebApplication running on the MEAN stack (Following the TraversyMedia Tutorial). However, I have ran into an issue and none of the solutions offered over here seem to work for me. Whenever I try to access my /profile page (which is protected unless you are authorized) I get the error returned. However, I am logged in and have a proper access token.

I have looked at the passport-jwt git. But what I have seems to match up.
I have tried to use:
`ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("bearer");`
`ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("bearer");`
`ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();`

Currently going with:
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("bearer") since none showed a difference.

I have looked into the HttpClientModule, but my call seems to be OK.

passport.js

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("bearer");
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, false);
        }

        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false);
        }
      });
    })
  );
};
```

users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/database");
const User = require("../models/user");

...

router.get(
  "/profile",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({ user: req.user });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

// Left some unrelated stuff out here

export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

...


  getProfile() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append("authorization", this.authToken);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http
      .get("http://localhost:3000/users/profile", {
        headers: headers
      })
      .pipe(map(res => res));
  }

...

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("id_token");
    this.authToken = token;
  }
```

profile.component.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(
      profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Expected to be directed to the profile page, but instead I am getting:

`GET http://localhost:3000/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)`

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/profile", ok: false, …}
error: "Unauthorized"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/users/profile: 401 Unauthorized"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
url: "http://localhost:3000/users/profile"
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Issue has been resolved. For anyone else having the same issue what solved it for me was:

replacing:

`   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append("authorization", this.authToken);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
`
With:
`
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: this.authToken
    });
    this.loadToken();
`

Comment: Consider posting a self-answer if your issue was resolved so the question doesn't show up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. For anyone else having the same issue what solved it for me was: replacing:

`let headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
this.loadToken(); 
headers.append("authorization", this.authToken); 
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");`

With:

`const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
"Content-Type": "application/json", 
Authorization: this.authToken 
}); 
this.loadToken();`